# Count unique references

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have reference numbers in column `H` and status of repair in column `R` (yes or no).

I am trying to count the unique reference numbers in column `H` only if column `R` is `No`.

I currently have the formula `=SUM(- -(Frequency(H2:H58,H2:H58)>0))`, which provides me with a count of the unique reference number. However, can you advise me how to update this to count unique reference numbers in `H2:H58` only if `R2:R58 = No`

Comment: A good phrase to Google for this would be "Excel Count unique numeric values with criteria". Lots of resources available explaining how to do this. Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you. I have spent some time looking at this but not having much luck, hopefully someone will be able to help with a suitable formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to look at only the data that meet your criteria.

Adjust the references to account for where your data is on your worksheet.

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B1:B8="No",A1:A8,""),IF(B1:B8="No",A1:A8,""))>0))
```

This is an **array** formula. In some versions of Excel, to enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

Comment: Thank you, can you advise me how I should complete the formula above after “No” I can’t see the end of the formula. Thank you

Comment: @Amc There should be a scroll bar below the formula to allow you to see the rest of it.  And you should be able to select/copy/paste the formula.  However, the part after "No" is  "`,A1:A8,""))>0))`" without the surrounding double quotes `"`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me.

Comment: Glad to help. Since my answer seems to be what you require, kindly mark it as Accepted.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

With Office 365 subscription one can use the Dynamic Array formulas:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(H:H,R:R="No")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I gave this a try and received message this function isn’t valid, do you have any other thoughts please?

Comment: isn't valid?  or you get `#NAME` error?

Comment: The response isn’t valid

Comment: interesting, as you can see by my edit, it works for me.  I would expect the `#NAME` error if you did not have the dynamic array formula.  But for it not be a valid input, would be something else.  Does your local setting require `;` instead of `,` for the delimiter?

Comment: It doesn’t seem to like filter

Comment: Try this: `=SEQUENCE(3)`.  What does that return?

Comment: Sorry, where would this be placed in the full formula

Comment: By itself I just want to know what happens.

Comment: #name? Is the response

Comment: then you do not have the Dynamic Array formula.  And will need to wait till someone can give you a formula that works for previous versions, but if you have Office 365 subscription, maybe update Excel and then you will have these new formula.

Comment: Thank you for your time